# How can I change the review body placeholder text in a gmail review action?

Tags: google-schemas

When I send someone an email with a review action, the text box says `Write a review. It will be published under your {{publisher}} account on their website.`  The text disappears when you focus the box to type your review.

We'd like to use a more specific prompt.  How can I change the placeholder text?